# Retrieve JSON data depending on current URL in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I'm using AngularJS to display a list of images fetched via JSON. Right now I have the JSON URL statically coded, but I'd like to have the JSON URL change depending on the current page.

For example, if I'm on /albums/test123 the URL retrieved would be /j/albums/test123

How can I do this?

html

```
<div data-ng-controller="AlbumController">
  <ul class="album_list">
    <li data-ng-repeat="img in media_list">
      <img data-ng-src="((img.s1_url))" data-ng-style="height: {{img.s1_height}}px; width: {{img.s1_width}}px;" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

main.js

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
myApp.config(function($interpolateProvider){
  $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('((').endSymbol('))');
  }
);

myApp.controller("AlbumController", function($http, $scope){
  $http.get('/j/albums/album52').success(function(data) {
    $scope.media_list = data;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

$location should do the trick I guess with some code like below :

[https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24location)

```
myApp.controller("AlbumController", function($http, $scope, $location){
  $scope.jsonUrl = '/j/' + $location.path();
  $http.get($scope.jsonUrl).success(function(data) {
    $scope.media_list = data;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to define the routing using ng-routes,
 Once the routes are defined something like

```
.when('/album/:id', {
templateUrl: '/tpl/album/view', controller: 'AlbumCtrl'
```

You can inject `$routeparams` to controller and do something like this

```
var albumId = $routeParams.albumid;
$http.get('/j/albums/' + albumId).success(function(data) {
    $scope.media_list = data;
});
```